# bidirectional self referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple database with 2 models:

```
class Fighter < ActiveRecrod::Base
   has_many :fights
   has_many :opponents, through :fights
end

class Fight < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :fighter
   belongs_to :opponent, class_name: 'Fighter'
 end`
```

What should I add for this to work:

```
a = Fighter.create
b = Fighter.create
a.opponents << b
b.fights <- should return a value`
```

`a.fights` should return newly created Fight

`b.fights` should return newly created Fight as well

so far only `a.fights` returns the value

I came up with such idea:

```
class Fight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fighter
  belongs_to :opponent, class_name: 'Fighter'
  after_create :create_association

  def create_association
    Fighter.find(opponent_id).fights << self
  end
end
```

but calling another model from Fight doesn't seem right.

I also tried to overload `has_man :fights` in `Fighter` so that it takes lambda

`has_many :fights, -> { where("fighter_id = ? OR opponent_id = ?", self.id, self.id)`
 but I constantly get error - wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

after researching a bit, I know I should use a bidirectional self-referential association, similar to this: [Bidirectional self referential associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923692/bidirectional-self-referential-associations)

but when follow this, then I receive two records of a fight in table `Fight`. One that is associated with one fighter and another that is associated with second fighter.

I would appreciate help or some hints in how to solve this issue

Comment: can you also include your attempt to follow the post you linked? It would help understand what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to define inverse relationships (as suggested in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)), I don't think you can avoid creating two fights every time. Your idea of using `after_create` would work, just you need to add the opponent and not the fight itself, like so:

```
class Fight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fighter
  belongs_to :opponent, class_name: 'Fighter'

  after_create :create_association

  def create_association
    opponent = Fighter.find(opponent_id)
    unless opponent.opponents.include?(fighter)
      Fighter.find(opponent_id).opponents << fighter
    end
  end
end
```

Inverse relationships would be better in terms of performance and storage, but not as seamless to use:

```
class Fighter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fights
  has_many :opponents, through: :fights

  has_many :inverse_fights, :class_name => "Fight", :foreign_key => "opponent_id"
  has_many :inverse_opponents, :through => :inverse_fights, :source => :fighter
end
```

From here, if you want all opponents for a fighter, you should do `a_fighter.opponents + a_fighter.inverse_opponents`

Comment: it works! the inversed relationship works well for my case. Thanks for help. Marking it as an answer